# Compilation problem when trying to pull a specific index in an array

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new to Java but having trouble with my code working properly. What I'm trying to do with my code is pull a specific String value. I have managed to code correctly to pull everything. However, I am unable to figure out how to pull just one value.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

public class SolarSystem {

```
public SolarSystem() {

}

public String[] getPlanets() {
    String[] planets = {"Sun", "Mercury", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Neptune", "Saturn"};
    return planets;
}

public getEarth() {
    return planets[2];
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    SolarSystem planets = new SolarSystem();
    SolarSystem justEarth = new SolarSystem();
    String[] fullList  = planets.getPlanets();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fullList));
    String[] earth = justEarth.getEarth();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(earth));


}
```

}

I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>           The method getEarth() is undefined for the type SolarSystem

```
    at SolarSystem.main(SolarSystem.java:25)
```

Comment: The method's "signature" is not valid since you need to give the getEarth() method a valid return type. So not `public getEarth() {` but rather `public String getEarth() {`

Comment: You also need to make planets an instance variable.